# How to trigger resize in if statement

Tags: jquery

I managed to detach a specific content that is on my sidebar and inserted before my navigation bar using jQuery so the code looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($(window).width() < 1000 ){
    $(".red").detach().insertBefore(".blue");
  }
});
```

```css
.red{
  background: red;
}
.green{
  background: green;
}
.blue{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<div class="main_container">
<p>This is the paragraph</p>
  <a href="#">This is a link text</a>

</div>
<div class="red">
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, dicta modi ratione sit cupiditate qui tempore soluta, optio consequatur in vero. Qui deleniti voluptates quod, distinctio aperiam provident tempore facere.</h1>
</div>
<div class="green">
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, dicta modi ratione sit cupiditate qui tempore soluta, optio consequatur in vero. Qui deleniti voluptates quod, distinctio aperiam provident tempore facere.</h1>
</div>
<div class="blue">
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, dicta modi ratione sit cupiditate qui tempore soluta, optio consequatur in vero. Qui deleniti voluptates quod, distinctio aperiam provident tempore facere.</h1>
</div>
```

But then I noticed that if I go back to big screens, the content does not go back to the sidebar.

How can I detach my sidebar content and place it wherever I want on devices smaller than 600px and put it back on the sidebar if the width of the screen if bigger than 600px?

Hope you can help.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, but `trigger('resize')` will answer the question you pose in the title. If you're trying to make your UI responsive I'd strongly suggest you do it in CSS where possible, and not in JS.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 600){   
        $("#mobile_sidebar").detach().insertBefore(".home_page_banner");
    }   
});
```

Comment: I tried the code and it partially works. If am on a big screen and resize the page down it works. But as soon as I scale the page up again, the content does not go back to the sidebar